# Initialize phonegap application when launch from the background

Tags: android, performance, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I use a push plugin in my application. When I click on notification my application open in which we're left (like as: third page) of my application. I need every time when application starts it's state from initialize state (home page or application restart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Cordova events like "resume" to move back to the Home when app is resumed
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html